# Какие использовать единицы для адаптивной вёрстки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Под конец запутался c применением единиц измерения в адаптивной вёрстке. 
Кто-то на StackOverflow посоветовал всё прописывать в vh, но как выяснилось, это оказалось неверным решением.
Пожалуйста, подскажите по приложенному коду моей страницы где vh необходимо заменить на другие величины и почему.

```css
@import url("/css/oblacheniya.css");
@import url("/css/oblacheniya-type-select.css");
@import url("/css/product-page.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz');

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2vh solid black;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 1vh solid black;
}
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    width: 11.1vh;
    height: 11vh;
    padding-top: 0.8vh;
    padding-right: 11.5vh;
  }
.logo img {
    width: 11.3vh;
    height: 11vh;
    margin: 0vh auto;
    padding-top: 0vh;
}
.main_title {
    padding-top: 0.2vh;
    margin-left: 0vh;
    padding-right: 0vh;
    font-size: 4vh;
    font-family: ImpactI, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0vh 0.4vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
    text-align: center;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.14vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  padding-right: 0vh
}
.second_subtitle {
    font-size: 2.3vh;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: ImpactI, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0.1vh 0.05vh 0.3vh rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    letter-spacing: -0.055vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -0.2vh;
}
.top_navigation-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1.5vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.top_navigation-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}
.top_navigation-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.top_navigation-menu li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.top_navigation-menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.35vh;
    font-family: Courier New Cyr, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.container1 ul {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}
.container1 ul li {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}
.container1 ul li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
}
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/
.spisok {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 1.6vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid #000;
  border-left: 1.5vh solid #000;
  border-right: 0vh solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.spisok li {
  width: 24vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 0.45vh;
}

#oblacheniya {
  
}
.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  }

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 4vh;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.button.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0vh;
}
.spisok ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.spisok ul li a p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 15.8vh;
  height: 3vh;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 0.1vh;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 0.2vh;
}
/*Начало SECTION*/
section {
  background: url(/img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-top: 0vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 0vh solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 109.9vh;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  width: 100%;
  height: 106.9vh;
}
.photo-price {
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-price {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
.text-price {
  font-size: 2.3vh;
  font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration-skip-ink:none;
}

.text-price p {
  padding-left: 2vh;
}
#first_abzac {
  margin-top: -2vh; 
}
.photo-price {
  height: 97vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-price {
  max-width: 10vh;
}
.choose_otstup {
 margin-left: 1vh;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 4.7vh;
  font-family: ImpactI;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0.5vh;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink:none;
  text-align: center;
  
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2.1vh;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
}
/*НАЧАЛО FOOTER*/
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;;
  border-top: 1vh solid black;;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid black;;
}
/*КОНЕЦ FOOTER*/
```

```html
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/head.php';
?>
<body>
 <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="content-wrapper">
   <header>
     <div class="container1">
      <div class="logo">
       <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="ШвейПокров"> 
      </div>
      <div class="main_title">
       "ШвейПокров"
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Православная швейная мастерская
      </div>
      <div class="second_subtitle">
       доставка по всей России
      </div>
      <ul class="top_navigation-menu">
        <li><a href="/index.php">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
        <li id="about-us-nav"><a href="/about.php">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </header>

   <main>
     
     <section>
      <div class="container2">
       <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
           <div class="photo-price">
            <div class="text-price">
               <p id="first_abzac"><u><b>Облачения</b></u>:</p>
                   <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> &nbsp; рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
                   <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>&nbsp;</strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
                  <p><u><b>Подрясники</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Подризники</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Рясы</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Стихари</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Скуфии</b></u>:&nbsp;от 800 рублей;</p>
                  <p><u><b>Камилавки</b></u>:&nbsp;от 1700</p>
                  <p><u><b>Крещальные</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Облачения для храма</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Вышитые кресты</b></u>:</p>
                  <p><u><b>Кадильный уголь</b></u>:</p>
                              <p class="choose_otstup">*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
                           </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     </section>
    </main>
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: 1vh = 1% , вообще единица измерения сугубо индивидуально выбирается ,если умеете делать на старых и добрых пикселях делайте на них ..

Comment: но то что вы делаете line-height padding margin width height писать в vw vh - это мягко сказать не верно

Comment: достаточно обычных пикселей и медиа запросов

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский а что использовать помимо vh/vw для перечня этих свойств?

Comment: я же написал - пикселей хватит - а 100vw 100vh только для body и то только для мобилок и планшетов

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский т.е. можно вообще без  vh всё делать? Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на какой-нибудь урок по теме использования разных видлв единиц вычисления?

Comment: я такого видео не видел